# Solidity: Smart Contract, always get wrong result

Tags: solidity, smart-lock

I'm writing a token locker contract, code as following:

```solidity
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "./SafeMath.sol";
import "./ERC20.sol";

contract TokenLocker {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    address public creator;
    address public owner;

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    constructor(address _creator, address _owner) public payable {
        creator = _creator;
        owner = _owner;
    }

    function() payable public {
        emit Received(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    function unlock() public returns(bool) {
        uint256 balance = address(this).balance;
        require(balance > 0, "No token available !");

        owner.transfer(balance);

        emit Unlock(owner, balance);

        return true;
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns(uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    event Received(address from, uint256 amount);
    event Unlock(address to, uint256 amount);
}
```

```
contract TokenLockerFactory {
    address public creator;
    mapping(address => address) ownerLockers; // map owner-locker relation
    address[] private lockerList;

    function createLocker(address _owner, uint256 amount) public payable 
            returns(address locker) {
        locker = ownerLockers[_owner];

        if(locker == address(0)) {
            // Create new locker.
            locker = (new TokenLocker).value(amount)(msg.sender, _owner);
            ownerLockers[_owner] = locker;
            lockerList.push(locker);

            // Emit event.
            emit Created(locker, msg.sender, _owner);
        }
    }


    function getLocker(address _owner) public view returns(address) {
        return ownerLockers[_owner];
    }

    function getLockersNumber() public view returns(uint256) {
        return lockerList.length;
    }
}
```

When call `createLocker`, I can get a correct locker address return, but when I then call `getLocker` with the related _owner address, I always get a `00000000000000000000` return, even call `getLockersNumber()` to check `lockerList` but always get a 0 return.

What is the problem? anybody can help? thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you call `createLocker`?  Do you publish transaction or just evaluate it locally?

Comment: Just evaluate it locally.

Comment: Then, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke `createLocker` in transaction via `send` like this:

```
myContract.methods.createLocker(owner, amount).send ({from: ..., value: amount});
```

rather than via `call`.  Then, to know address of new created `Locker` contract you need to check for `Created` events via [`myContract.events.Created`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events).

When you invoke `createLocker` via `call` modifications made by the method are not persisted in blockchain, that's why subsequent calls cannot see them.

Comment: Thank you Mikhail, I'll take a try to see, will get back to let you know. thanks